# Silverlight 4 Datagrid not updating when new entity added to DomainContext's entity set. (Binding problem?)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid bound to a DomainDataSource:

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="Auto"
     ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mailboxDomainDataSource, Path=Data,Mode=TwoWay}"   
     Name="mailboxHeaderDataGrid"....>...</sdk>
```

I also have an add button to add a new row:

```
    private void addMailboxButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Mailbox m = new Mailbox();

        InboxNotifierDomainContext context = (InboxNotifierDomainContext)mailboxDomainDataSource.DomainContext;
        ((InboxNotifierDomainContext)mailboxDomainDataSource.DomainContext).Mailboxes.Add(m);
        if (!mailboxDomainDataSource.DomainContext.IsSubmitting) if (mailboxDomainDataSource.HasChanges) mailboxDomainDataSource.SubmitChanges();
        mailboxHeaderDataGrid.ItemsSource = ((InboxNotifierDomainContext)mailboxDomainDataSource.DomainContext).Mailboxes;

        foreach (Mailbox m1 in ((InboxNotifierDomainContext)mailboxDomainDataSource.DomainContext).Mailboxes)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(m1.MailboxID + '-' + m1.MailBox1);
        }
    }
```

Now, when I iterate through DomainContext.Mailboxes, as at the end of the function, the new mailbox exists.

When I look in my database, the new mailbox exists.

If I refresh the page, the new mailbox appears in the DataGrid.

*However*, when I iterate through the ItemsSource, the new mailbox doesn't appear (shouldn't it be the same as DomainContext.Mailboxes, since I set them equal?).  And the new mailbox doesn't appear in the grid.

Any help would be wonderful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favourite way to do this is as follows:

```
InboxNotifierDomainContext _context = mailboxDomainDataSource.DomainContext as InboxNotifierDomainContext;

_context.EntityContainer.GetEntitySet<Mailbox>().EntityAdded += (s,e) => {mailBoxGrid.ItemsSource = mailboxDomainDataSource.DomainContext.EntityContainer.GetEntitySet<Mailbox>();};
```

Alternatively, you can use the event args to get the added entity, cast it as a mailbox and and it to the ItemsSource--this was just the lazy way.

**Might as well take advantage of C# being event-driven!**

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the following line in your code, setting the ItemsSource = null before assigning a new one:

```
// Set ItemsSource to null
mailboxHeaderDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
// Assign new ItemsSource
mailboxHeaderDataGrid.ItemsSource = ((InboxNotifierDomainContext)mailboxDomainDataSource.DomainContext).Mailboxes;
```

However, looking at the xaml and the code I think you have some inconsistency there.
In your xaml you use `Binding ElementName=mailboxDomainDataSource, Path=Data` and in your code you assign a new ItemsSource.

I believe a cleaner way would be to use an `ObservableCollection<Mailbox>` (namespace System.Collections.ObjectModel) as the ItemsSource and fill that with the results of the DomainDataSource. Use the DomainDataSource.LoadedData-Event and copy the results. (Something like this, not tested:)

```
private ObservableCollection<Mailbox> _mailboxCollection = new ObservableCollection<Mailbox>();
public ObservableCollection<Mailbox> MailboxCollection { ... }

private void DomainDataSource_LoadedData(object sender, LoadedDataEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.HasError)
  {
    // Error handling
  }
  else
  {
    if (e.Entities.Count > 0)
    {
      this.MailboxCollection = new ObservableCollection(e.Entities);
    }
  }
}
```

Then, when you add a new Mailbox, you can do this:

```
((InboxNotifierDomainContext)mailboxDomainDataSource.DomainContext).Mailboxes.Add(m);
this.MailboxObservableCollection.Add(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is better way to do it,

```
private void addMailboxButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Mailbox m = new Mailbox();
     mailboxDomainDataSource.DataView.Add(m);
     // it takes a little while for Datagrid to update so 
     // we will queue our selection logic
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( ()=>{
         mailBoxGrid.SelectedItem = m;
     } );
}
```